# NHibernate returns associated set with null-elements

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one problem with NHibernate (C#, MVC3). I have two related one-to-many tables: Sources and Filters (one Source to many Filters).

Mapping for sources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Core" namespace="Core.Model">
  <class name="Source" table="Sources">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    ... properties ...
    <list name="Filters" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false">
      <key column="SourceId" />
      <index column="FilterIndex" />
      <one-to-many class="Filter" />
    </list>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mapping for filters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Core" namespace="Core.Model">
  <class name="Filter" table="Filters" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    ... properties ...
    <many-to-one name="Source" column="SourceId" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

All work

Problem is that when I get source record from database:

```
Source source = session.Get<Source>(id);
```

I get list of two items source.Filters = {null, Filter}. I don't understand how the list can contain null.
In database in Filters table exist only one row that returned together with null object in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In table Filters, the one row has FilterIndex=1.

[The documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues) notes that the index column for an indexed is numbered from zero.

Comment: Thanks! Absolutely. I found error - due to invalid conditions I tried to save this record again, but since table contains unique fields no new entries are added, but FilterIndex are incremented.